# php mail() function, from address not working properly

Tags: php, email

I have created a website and hosted on a free server from 000webhost. I am sending an activation email for the registered users.

---

**code**

```
$to = "$email1";
$subject = 'Account Activation';
$message = '<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div style="margin-left: 100px">
                <h1 >Hello '.$username.'</h1>

                <p >&bull;&nbsp;This mail is for your account activation .</p></br>

                <p>&bull;&nbsp;Please click on the below link to get your account activated.</p></br>



                <p>&bull;&nbsp;Login with your username and password after activation.</p>
                </div>
           </body>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\n";

$headers .= 'From: <developer@mysite.com>' . "\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "success";
```

---

The problem is that whenever I send mail with from address shown above, the mails are not sent. The problem lies in that one line where i use from address in headers because if use some other names such as 'name@example.com' (here example is some other name) the mails are sent. The problem comes whenever i use mail provided by my hosting server. Can anyone help please?

Comment: sounds like the domain is being blocked.  is there anything in the mail log about it?

Comment: Does "no-reply@your-site.com" work when "name@your-site.com" not ?

Comment: The values in the $headers argument supplied to the PHP mail() command need to be separated with CRLF, not just LF. So you shoudl be appending `'\r\n'` to the `From: ...` header value. This may not be your issue, but it's what the PHP documentation explicitly calls for. And it *might* be your issue.

Comment: @Kulvar no it's not working.

Comment: @Craig I knew that, but php manual says if \r\n doesn't work try with \n. So, I was experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP: mail() $additional_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n)

So split headers with `\r\n`:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <developer@mysite.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: I knew that, but php manual says if \r\n doesn't work try with \n.

Answer (score 0):

Check your $to is working or not.

or check spam folder in the recipient's mail.

Otherwise all thing is ok.

Further clarification go [func_mail_mail](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

Comment: If you can't answer the question please don't down vote the question. I tried every possible thing and it is still not working.

Comment: @lonecoder, I dont down vote the question. use the chaos theory. go and check from the starting point. make sure $email1, and enter manuall values in mail(). after that check all the variable.